# Html2canvas renders page with wrong layout in IE11 whed devtools not opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html2canvas

I am trying to fix bug in related to rendering web page to canvas via `html2canvas` in IE11. Issues is a bit confusing: site implements responsible layout with bootstrap 2.3 grid.

1. When developer tools **not opened** it is rendered like **for table/smartphones screen**.
2. But if I press F12 (**developer tools opens**, no any other action performed) and click to render page **it rendered as expected, for wide screen**.

Removed outdated link to old application. Not it does not exists on specified address.

This issue reproduced onli in IE11 and disappears once devtool are opened, so I event do not know how to debug it.

Comment: Is it defaulting to Quirks mode when the dev tools aren't open? In the Dev tools set the Document Mode to Quirks and see if it looks the same as it does before the Dev tools are open.

Comment: @ericjbasti, in IE11 there is not such option in Document model. Only "Edge", "10", "9", "8", "7" and "5".

Comment: Also I dont see a meta tag for `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>` in the head. Your DOCTYPE looks good though.

Comment: @ericjbasti this site does not works in IE8 and lesser. In 10 and 9 all works the same way - mobile layout when devtools closed and wide-screen when it is open.

Comment: Tried to add `meta` tag (I tested it before) - no effect, it is really confusing bug.

Comment: Remove all of your Console Log statements, and see if the issue persists. Thats really the only time I've ever had an issue resolve itself by opening the dev tools.

Comment: Oh, I heard about that issue. Unfortunately no, after removing of `console.log` issue still persists. Maybe it is issue of specific IE11 build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am actually do not know what the hell with IE11, but I found a fast monkey-patching way to solve it:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var documentClone = container.contentWindow.document;

        /* Chrome doesn't detect relative background-images assigned in inline <style> sheets when fetched through getComputedStyle
         if window url is about:blank, we can assign the url to current by writing onto the document
         */
        container.contentWindow.onload = container.onload = function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (documentClone.body.childNodes.length > 0) {
                    initNode(documentClone.documentElement);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    if (options.type === "view") {
                        container.contentWindow.scrollTo(x, y);
                        if ((/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g).test(navigator.userAgent) && (container.contentWindow.scrollY !== y || container.contentWindow.scrollX !== x)) {
                            documentClone.documentElement.style.top = (-y) + "px";
                            documentClone.documentElement.style.left = (-x) + "px";
                            documentClone.documentElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                        }
                    }
                    resolve(container);
                }
            }, 50);
        };

        documentClone.open();
        documentClone.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html></html>");
        // Chrome scrolls the parent document for some reason after the write to the cloned window???
        restoreOwnerScroll(ownerDocument, x, y);
        documentClone.replaceChild(documentClone.adoptNode(documentElement), documentClone.documentElement);

        /*
           #HERE
           1) It seems IE 11 does not get right computed styles when clones a node (See function cloneNode) above.
           2) In documentClone.replaceChild(...) IE 11 does not apply @media instructions.
              That's can be checked
                  by alert('ndocumentClone ' + $('.row-fluid [class*="span"]', documentClone).css('float'));
                  or alert('documentElement ' + $('.row-fluid [class*="span"]', documentElement).css('float'));
              These both statments shows 'left' for wide screen in Chrome and shows none in IE11 (without dev panel).
            To fix that we need to re-apply styles somehow. Change the container width works but probably a better
            way exists. Lets have this in mind.
         */
        container.width = width + 1;
        /* * */

        documentClone.close();
    });
```

Comment: Had the same issue today. Spent much time debugging before I came to this thread. The whole code can be kept as it is of the original. Just the important bit is container.width = width + 1; Thank you so much. Upvoted.

Comment: This is not a good way if you are using bower for example. You need fix this without manipulate library, in my opinion. Im looking for the same way to do this...

Comment: for the version 1.0.0-alpha.12 ``cloneIframeContainer.width = (bounds.width + 1).toString();`` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody encounters this like I did:
html2canvas provides an onclone-method, in which you can touch the DOM before the screenshot is generated. This will also trigger the recomputation of styles in IE11.

```
html2canvas(
        document.body,
        {
            allowTaint: true,
            logging: false,
            onclone: function(document) {
                return $q(
                    function(resolve) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML; //<-- Hackerman was here
                            resolve();
                        }, 0);
                });
            }
        }
);
```

This did the trick for me, with the upside of me not having to modify the implementation i got from npm.
- Though i'd love it if somebody has a better solution, since this seems quite hacky